# How do you narrow down a series of arrays?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have several arrays. And I want to narrow them down, so that at the end, whatever comes out, are values that are seen in all of the other arrays so long as those arrays are not nil.

**My sad attempt at coding:**

```
array_of_users = []
array_of_users & @zip_ids if !@zip_ids.empty?
array_of_users & @sex_ids if !@sex_ids.empty?
array_of_users & @interest_ids if !@interest_ids.empty?
array_of_users & @age_ids if !@age_ids.empty?
```

Logically, I would *think* this would work because its finding the similarity in each one so long as its not empty, but it doesn't actually add them to the array.

How would you accomplish this?

Comment: The intersection of `[]` and anything else will always be `[]`.  I can't really tell what you're trying to do from your example.  It looks like you want to filter an array based on various criteria?  Maybe `Array#select` would be more appropriate?

Comment: Just to clarify- You want only values that are in all of the arrays, and not a list of unique values, right? In math terms, you want an intersection, not a union?

Comment: @Chris, yes I want an intersection. But it has to be an interesection that saves the data into the `array_of_users`. As you can see and @cam's comment is correct, an intersection of `[]`, is still `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
users = [@zip_ids,@sex_ids,@interest_ids,@age_ids].reject(&:empty?).reduce(&:&)
```

Comment: Hmm.. both of those do not yield any results.

Comment: Oh, sorry, the first one would have failed if the first array were empty. I deleted it. The second (now only) one should be fine, and works in my test.

Comment: It's so strange because @digitalRoss's answer is good to, I feel, but for some reason both asnwers return an `empty` array.

Comment: Ah I got it. Its because they have to be flattened to be empty. Thanks Glenn!

Answer (score 2):

Think about it this way:

> ([1] | [2] | [3,4]) & [3,4]
>
> => [3,4]

So you could do:

> array_of_users = @zip_ids | @sex_ids | @interest_ids | @age_ids
>
> intersection = array_of_users & @zip_ids & @sex_ids & @interest_ids & @age_ids

Only, like @glenn says, it ignores the "dont merge if empty" requirement.

@DigitalRoss is good, but if the first array is empty, it all goes flat.

Favorite, then, from @glenn:

> [[],[1,2],[2],[2,3,4,4],[]].reject(&:empty?).reduce(&:&)
>
> => [2]

Comment: This won't work, as you forgot about the not-if-empty part. And it's a waste of time to union all those arrays when you're only going to intersect them again...

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually assign them to the array. At the point your code is sitting at, you're doing the intersection, but you're not actually assigning them to the array. You need to add ='s operators in there.

Here is an example setup:

```
>> x = [ 1, 1, 3, 5 ] 
>> y = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

This is what you're doing right now:

```
>> x & y
=> [1, 3]
>> x
=> [1, 1, 3, 5]
```

This is where it needs to go:

```
>> x &= y
=> [1, 3]
>> x
=> [1, 3]
```

Thus, this should get the job done:

```
array_of_users = []
array_of_users &= @zip_ids if !@zip_ids.empty?
array_of_users &= @sex_ids if !@sex_ids.empty?
array_of_users &= @interest_ids if !@interest_ids.empty?
array_of_users &= @age_ids if !@age_ids.empty?
```

Hope this helps- Sidenote: I did all of this in IRB (interactive ruby shell). It's your friend. :)

Comment: You're going to need to initialize `array_of_users` to something, otherwise you're intersecting with an empty array each time...

Comment: Ah, yeah, good catch Glenn- I should have mentioned that. Thanks!

Comment: this actually does not work, because `array_of_users` is an empty array, so it can only intersect with other empty arrays.

Comment: Yeh, that's what Glenn mentioned, and I assumed. - My assumption is that the array_of_users was already filled with the user set you want to narrow down. If that's not true, I can adjust my answer appropriately. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
[@z, @s, @i, @a].reject(&:empty?).inject { |m, e| m & e }
```

Comment: This makes the most sense to me out of any answer I've gotten, but it still returns an `empty` value.

Comment: Nope. This is the same as the one I wrote first. Won't work if the first array is empty, because in this form of `inject` the first element of the enumerable is used to initialize the variable, without being passed through the block.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000274) the method Array#& returns a NEW Array and does not modify the original one, so you would have to change your code to something like:

Assuming you want the IDs that are contained in all the four arrays that are not empty, I would try something like this:

```
ary = []
ids = [@zip_ids, @sex_ids, @interest_ids, @age_ids]
ids.each {|i|ary << i unless i.empty?}
ary.uniq!
result = ids.inject(ary){|res, ids| res & ids}
```

Comment: Great response! Everything works up until that last line. result simply returns `ids`

Answer (score 0):

As Glenn suggests, the most idiomatic way to do this is probably

```
users = [@zip_ids, @sex_ids, @interest_ids, @age_ids].reject(&:empty?).reduce(&:&)
```

However, this depends on the behavior of #hash and #eql? for the objects in the array. Since the implementation of Object#hash is based on object_id, Array#& for User objects (presumably using the default Object#hash impl) will compare object ids, not whatever values define equality semantics for your object.

A solution that allows you to compare arrays of User objects rather than just their ids would be to define #hash and #eql? semantics for your object and then use Array#&. For instance:

```
class User
  # ...

  def hash
    [self.class, *equality_attributes].map(&:hash).reduce(:^)
  end

  def eql?(other)
    self.class == other.class &&
      self.equality_attributes == other.equality_attributes
  end

  # ...

  private

  def equality_attributes
    [name, address]
  end
end
```